# Call gallery images randomly from databse, overlapping at intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, css

```
(function makeDiv(){
var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px',
    'background-color': color
});

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

$newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(700).delay(3500).fadeOut(300, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   makeDiv(); 
}); 
})();
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/

Design mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEJOJ.jpg

I've tried fiddling with this code I found but I just end up butchering it and breaking it. In one instance I had the code doubling the objects every iteration and it almost crashed my PC, heh.

I need a few things happening here.

- I need there to be at least 8 of these objects simultaneously performing this appearing and disappearing act, overlapping each other slightly offset (centerOffset?). Each appearing square should be in the front of previous images that still linger.
- The objects are not colored squares, but should be images called randomly from a database (an inventory of products).
- When you mouseover any of the pictures, the process should pause and that object will come to the front while you keep your mouse on it, displaying some text about the piece. If you click it it will navigate you away to the items page.

Note: The random sizing element is nice but I have some taller images, some wider images, etc. Not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a bit of animation/timing work to keep 8 objects simultaneously appearing/disappearing. The next hard bit is capturing the mouseover the objects and when to "come to the front", you might need the jQuery *hover intent* plugin. Anyways, here's some working code that will simultaneously animate 8 random objects onto the screen, and the appearing/disappearing act will stop when you mouseover an object. When your mouse leaves the object, the animation will continue: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/Q6XKv/

The main gist is this (see fiddle for full code):

```
// Adds the box and animates in/out
var addBox = function () {
    var makeBox = function () {
        var divsize = ((Math.random() * 100) + 50).toFixed();
        var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
        var newBox = $('<div class="box" id="box' + boxIds + '"/>').css({
            'width': divsize + 'px',
                'height': divsize + 'px',
                'background-color': color
        });
        return newBox;
    };
    var newBox = makeBox();
    var boxSize = newBox.width();
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - boxSize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - boxSize)).toFixed();
    newBox.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
            'left': posx + 'px',
            'top': posy + 'px',
            'display': 'none'
    }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(ANIMATE_SPEED / 2, function () {
        if (timer !== null) {
            $(this)
            .delay(ANIMATE_SPEED * MAX_BOXES)
            .fadeTo(1, 1, function () {
                if (timer !== null) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    removeBox(id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    boxIdList.push(boxIds++);
    lastBox = newBox;
    numBoxes++;
    return newBox;
};


// Add the boxes in at interval animateSpeed, if there's too many then don't add
var animateBox = function () {
    if (numBoxes < MAX_BOXES) {
        addBox();
    } else {
        removeBox(boxIdList[0]);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(animateBox, ANIMATE_SPEED); // re-set timer for the next interval
};

// starts everything off
var start = function () {
    timer = setTimeout(animateBox, ANIMATE_SPEED);
};
```

This should be enough for you to work off of to add the level of detail you want for the interaction and effects.